# How to add sound in sound player from resource WPF

Tags: wpf, resources, soundplayer

How can i add this sound [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ayIP.png)

like i make it with background in xaml.

```
<Controls:FlipView.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Gamedata/MainMenuBackground.jpg"/>
            </Controls:FlipView.Background>
```

I already have tried this , but it didn't help

```
SoundPlayer PlaySound = new SoundPlayer(@"pack://application:,,,/Gamedata/Sounds/MenuClick.wav");
        PlaySound.Load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but to play a sound with the SoundPlayer class you use the `Play()` method.  To load it from a resource, add it to your Resources.resx file and use Properties.Resources.resourceName.

```
SoundPlayer PlaySound = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.MenuClick);
PlaySound.Play();
```